# Is it possible to amplify a sine voltage by a factor of 190?

Tags: power, batteries, voltage, amplifier

I would like to amplify a sinusoidal wave (-1.23V to +1.23V) to a wave between -230V and +230V.
I am planning to use a 12V@8.1Ah battery as my Vcc source.

My question, Is this idea possible? If it is, what references should I use?

Comment: What is the frequency? What is the power output?

Comment: If you are asking this question, I think you should stay away from dangerous voltages. Yes, I know the current might no be much, but you need to be careful.

Comment: What are you trying to achieve? Are you hoping to build a mains voltage inverter / UPS by any chance?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it is possible.

A simple passive transformer is within your specs.  You'd need a turns ratio of about 190.  This won't be all that efficient if the transformer isn't carefully designed for this case.

Keep in mind that the input current relative to the output will need to be higher at least by the turns ratio, just like the output voltage relative to the input is higher by the turns ratio.  For example, if you want 10 mA out, then just from conservation of energy alone you know you need 1.9 A in.  Since efficiency won't be 100%, you'll need somewhat more than that in practice.

Comment: Turns ratio of 190?

Comment: @Michael: Yes, as I clearly stated in the second paragraph, second sentence.

Answer (score 0):

It's possible but it'll be problematic.

The first thing is to be clear about what you want to do : 230V peak will give about 165V rms : is this really what you want, or did you mean 230V rms, i.e. 320V peak?

And what sort of load do you need to drive from it? You won't be able to draw much power for long from such a small lead acid battery.

Next, you will need to decide how to get the AC output voltage you want. There are two basic ways with reasonable efficiency :

1. Use a **switch mode power supply** to get an adequate DC supply (230 or 320V DC), then use a **PWM amplifier** in an **H-bridge** to generate the AC supply from that. The bold terms would make useful search terms)
2. Use PWM at 12V, into a transformer to generate 230V (peak or RMS). In an H-bridge, 12V DC can give you 12V peak (24V peak-to-peak). You can probably find a **Class D audio amplifier** which will do this job for you.

Starting from 12V peak, you need a turns ratio of 19:1 for 230V peak, or 27:1 for 230V rms. For a suitable range of frequencies, the latter can be a standard 12V mains transformer operated in reverse.

Or

3). (only if it's 230Vrms 50Hz you need) Use a 230V inverter designed for car battery use, and save a lot of design work.